# Formal principles and processes for designing an API (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, api-design

While I have some development experience, I have yet to design APIs or larger scale projects.

My general process usually involves something along:

1. Coming up with a few proposed designs.
2. Enlist their pros and cons.
3. Given a set of scenarios (X changes, new feature added, etc) -- how does the design react to it.

This is my own "style"; I am wondering where can i read more about **formal processes** and methodologies for doing such things? (online, books, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the book The Clean Coder, and Also Agile Principles, Patters, and Practices in C#, and lastly Clean Code all written by Robert C. Martin. I like the way he writes, I like his style of coding and it has given me tons to think about and apply to my own professional career as a programmer. You can get all those books for fairly cheap on Amazon. Also Robert C. Martin has his own website for this sort of stuff. http://www.objectmentor.com/omTeam/martin_r.html this is the website featuring him in the "About our team part." poke around there and see if you can't find his other website, and a program he wrote called Fitnesse.

Although your style looks good for normal sized projects that hobbyists tend to have on larger scales it may be a few more steps involved. What Online service were you thinking of writing for? I am currently writing another one for Zoho, but I keep forgetting to import my code from work into my program.

Answer (score 4):

The [Framework Design Guidelines](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Libraries/dp/0321246756) is a great book for this.  Also, the [.NET Framework Standard Library Annotated Reference](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Framework-Standard-Library-Annotated-Reference/dp/0321154894) is another great book.

Here's some of the principals I've followed:

- **Less is more**: taking away features makes users more productive more quickly as there are fewer concepts to learn.  Less is more leads to a...
- **Low barrier to entry**: users expect to learn the basics of a new framework/API very quickly.  They want to learn by experimentation and not by reading documentation.  Most only take the time to fully understand a feature if it's particularly interesting or to move beyond basic scenarios
- **Type names should be noun phrases**: they represent entities of the system. Names should also represent ***scenarios***. The **most easily recognised names** should be used for **the most commonly used types**, even if better better suited to a less commonly used type. The examples giving in the FDG book is `Printer` and `PrintQueue`, where `Printer` would be the most easily recognised but `PrintQueue` would better describe the concept.  Which leads to...
- **Concentrate on abstractions and not concepts**.  The examples used are the `File` base class in .NET and the derived `NtfsFile`.  Most devs would automatically try to instantiate a `File`, only to discover it's `abstract`.  Inheritance like this works well in *implementation*, but...
- **Framework design is not the same as OO design**: for example, in .NET there is a hierarchy of objects; `Stream`, `StreamReader`, `TextReader`, `StringReader`, and `FileStream`.  There is a clear hierarchy but this is confusing when thinking of a ***scenario***, e.g. reading a file.
- **Assemblies represent packaging and deployment boundaries**.  Best practices (in .NET anyway) generally say that namespaces should match assemblies, e.g. `MyCompany.MyTechnology.dll` has a namespace `MyCompany.MyTechnology` and other namespaces, such as `MyCompany.MyTechnology.MyFeature`.  This isn't necessarily applicable to Frameworks/APIs; the assembly here should represent logical grouping for devs and allow for performance (load time), easy deployment, and easy versioning.  This is a balancing act; nobody likes referencing more than 1 assembly when just 1 will do.  And nobody likes taking dependencies on stuff they don't need if an assembly is too big and has poor logical grouping (e.g. having to take an additional dependency on ADFS even if the features you're using in the API have nothing to do with ADFS).

Answer (score 1):

I have just finished writing an API for one of our projects at work and I do have a few points.

Methodologies are great in principle, but think about your requirements. Will you have multiple developers progressing and maintaining the API going forward, or are you primarily responsible for development? If its the former, then a structured methodology and process for the architecture will pay dividends in the future when it comes to (dreaded but inevitable) change.

If it's the latter, then you have more flexibility. Every API is trying to achieve something different, whether it's a plugin framework, or a 'public' entry point to your service - I would recommend doing some requirements gathering and determining whether or not following one of the methodologies will benefit you.

Comment: I am the only current developer, planning to release it as open source. Kinda tough as am i the one making the requirements for myself.